# Reading returned xml from stored procedure C#

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql

Hi I got a hard time reading XML returned from a stored procedure I get the XML I want from executing the procedure on the SQL server

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUser]  
    @Username nvarchar(50)  
AS

select( SELECT * FROM "User" 
WHERE "User".Username = @Username   
FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS, ROOT('Users')) AS result
```

And my c# code here:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[GetUser]", conn))
{
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Username);
     cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     conn.Open();
     XmlReader reader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader();
}
```

The reader keeps getting the value of "none" what are my doing wrong please help
I just want the XML as a String

Hope you can help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get reader in result but not reading it:

```
 using (var xmlReader = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader())
        {
           while(xmlReader.Read())
           {
            string s = xmlReader.ReadOuterXml();      
           }
 }
```

But even that might have a problem because gives you a string.  [This link may give more details](http://www.media-division.com/converting_xmlreader_to_xmldocument_in_n/). Might need to work with `XPathDocument` if you will have missing info as result of work `ReadOuterXml`.